# How to bold line in one cell based on another cell in the same row

Tags: vba, if-statement

I am trying to bold the last line of a multi-line cell (column E), but specifically based on if another cell in the same row (column L) is blank/empty or not.  I have working code that bolds just the last line, but trying to incorporate the IF portion has me stuck.  This is what I have so far, and it keeps giving me a data mismatch error.

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

```
Sub BoldLastLine1()
Dim p As Long
Dim r As Range

For Each r In ActiveSheet.Range("A3:L100")
    If Len(Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(r, 12).Value)) <> 0 Then

        p = InStrRev(r.Value, vbLf)
        If p > 0 Then
            With r.Characters(p + 1, Len(r.Value) - p).Font
                .Bold = True
                .Size = 16
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next

MsgBox ("Updates Completed.")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cells`-property of a worksheet or range expects 2 numeric parameter for row and column. 
You are defining a Range `r` and passing it as first parameter, this causes the error.
You can use for example

```
If Len(Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(r.Row, 12).Value)) Then
```

This points to the cell in column 12 (=L) of the row of range `r`

UPDATE:
`Cells` accepts also a string as second parameter, you could also write

```
If Len(Trim(ActiveSheet.Cells(r.Row, "L").Value)) Then
```

Comment: Great, that works now!  How would I update the code so that it only updates the font in column E?  Right now, it's updating the font style for all multi-line cells for that row.